# How to access parent widget elements in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, desktop-application, kivy-language

I am working on a Kivy application. My app's design is shown in picture below:
[image]

I have two separate modules, **MainLayout and Table**. There is a label inside MainLayout named **'lblA'** and a button inside Table named **'btnA'**. Now I want to change **lblA**'s text on **btnA**'s click. But I am unable to create object of MainLayout in Table because MainLayout already has object of Table. Is there any solution to this problem ? I have spent a week with this issue but find no solution. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your problem with some code please.

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Comment: where is your code? All widgets should have function `self.parent()` to get access to parent object. Sometimes there are other objects between original object and expected parent and it may need many parents `self.parent().parent()`, etc. BTW: Don't create object `MainLayout` because it will create new object and it doesn't gives access to already existing object `MainLayout`.

Comment: Thanks @furas , I solved my problem by self.parent() property. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks @inclement, your post is very helpful.

Comment: Actually this is a situation I faced in my application and I don't want to post the code of my application, So I just post the situation. May be it is violation of website's rules but apologize from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is listed in comment section and I am posting it as well.
We can solve this using **parent** property of a module.

In my case, to change text of **lblA** on **btnA** click, Here is a simple code for **btnA's** click handler.
`self.parent.ids.lblA.text = "I am changed from btnA(which is in Table module)"`

Here, **self.parent** points to **MainLayout**, and inside that layout we have a label with id **lblA**.

> For more help: proceed to this link: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/